# Using macros in printf with a number sign

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I'm a bit confused about an explanation concerning macros in K&R 2nd Ed, p.90. Here is the paragraph:

> Formal parameters are not replaced within quoted strings. If, however, a parameter name is preceded by a # in the replacement text, the combination will be expanded into a quoted string with the parameter replaced by the actual argument.

I'm not sure what that second sentence is saying. It goes on to explain a use for this with a "debugging print macro".

> This can be combined with a string concatenation to make, for example, a debugging print macro:

```
#define dprint(expr) printf(#expr " = %g\n", expr);
```

Edit:

All the input was useful. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you define macro like this:

```
#define MAKE_STRING(X) #X
```

Then, you can do something like this:

```
puts(MAKE_STRING(a == b));
```

Which will expand into:

```
puts("a == b");
```

In the `dprint()` example, it is printing out a string form of the expression, as well as the expression value.

```
dprint(sin(x)/2);
```

Will expand into:

```
printf("sin(x)/2" " = %g\n", sin(x)/2);
```

String literal concatenation will treat the first parameter as a single string literal.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a neat feature where you can convert a macro parameter into a string literal which mainly is useful for debugging purposes. So

```
dprint(x + y);
```

is expanded by the C preprocessor to this

```
printf("x + y = %g\n", x + y);
```

Notice how the value of the parameter `expr` appears both inside the string literal and also in the code generated by the macro. For this to happen you need to prefix `expr` with `#` to create a string literal.

One thing worth pointing out is that adjacent string literals are combined into a single string literal, e.g. `"x + y" " = %g\n"` are combined into `"x + y = %g\n"`.

Answer (score 2):

`#expr` is expanded into `"expr"`. Two string literals next to each other are automatically concatenated. We can see that invoking `gcc -E` for `dprint(test)` will give the following output:

```
("test" " = %g\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://decompile.com/cpp/faq/file_and_line_error_string.htm) site may help. It describes how stringification can be implemented.